# Delphi Focus Problem seen by Caret

Tags: delphi, focus, components, caret

I have written an advanced text editor component (fixed-width, syntax highlighting, etc.) in Delphi, using Windows API combined with the TCanvas element, and it works great, except for one thing: If I set focus to another control inside the same application that displays a caret as well, such as a TEdit, stealing focus from my editor component, the caret of the new editor (such as TEdit) is not shown; instead the caret moves in my editor component! For example, if I write a character in the new editor (TEdit), it will show up as expected, and the caret will move to the right in my component. What can cause this? I suspect there is some conflict between Win API's handling of keyboard focus and the VCL handling. In my editor component, I use CreateCaret in response to WM_SETFOCUS and DestroyCaret in response to WM_KILLFOCUS. Apparently the problem only occurs if the new edit control is in a new, modal, window.

Comment: Without the code example one can only guess. May be your Text Editor component receives wrong WM_SETFOCUS message after it received WM_KILLFOCUS and actully lost focus.

Comment: Unfortunately, that wasn't it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a trivial bug in the component's code. My apologies.

Comment: Then please accept an answer (Loren's or yours). That will remove the unanswered flag.

Comment: I'll do that in four hours. (The server won't let me do it now.)

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be that you're not getting the WM_KILLFOCUS message.  I would construct a diagnostic to tell you whether it's happening or not.

I am *NOT* inclined to use a debugger for this sort of problem, I find doing things like modifying the title works better when trying to diagnose interactions like this.

Comment: Thanks, but I am positive that the code is executed. (I have tried with beep.)